# Differences in battery information and phones printed labels

Tags: battery, samsung

I just run across this today:
The value for battery current capacity printed on the battery of some Samsung Android devices are different than the numbers printed on the label on the phone (underneath the battery).
I tested 4 models (Galaxy S3, Galaxy S4, Galaxy Note II and Galaxy Pocket); The only consistent one was S3 (Phone label was 2100mA and battery was 2100mAh)
On S4, battery is 2600mAh, but the printed label is like this:

> RATED : 3.8 V ... 1300 mA

What's the difference between these two numbers and why on some phones these two values are not equal?
 Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know that this is answerable here. First of all, it's not really an Android question; you just happen to be looking at Android devices. Second, the only people who know why an advertised battery capacity is different than the actual are the ones who put it together. Maybe they got a new supplier. Maybe they can't get the old batteries anymore and can't change their copy. Maybe they just haven't gotten around to updating things. Maybe they are using old labels. Your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that the capacity printed on the battery is correct (as per manufacturer's claim, and information available in sites such as GSMArena, but the label prined on the back of phone is sometimes correct and sometimes incorrect)
Maybe that number has a different meaning (especially that it's not in "mAh", it's in "mA")

Comment: Ask Samsung - they make the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mA is not the same as mAh. The former is a current rating, and the latter is the capacity of the battery. 1000 mAh means the battery can supply a current of 1000 mA (at its rated voltage) for 1 hour, or equivalently, a current of 500 mA for 2 hours, etc. It tells you how much energy the battery can hold.

The number in mA printed on the phone tells you how much current the phone can draw. It's like a safety rating, though I suspect the numbers are somewhat made-up for phones: it would be very unusual for the phone to actually draw that much current, and most of the time the amount drawn will be much less.

There's no reason for those two numbers to be the same.

Comment: So, the number printed on the phone (in mA) is the maximum current draw. Right?

Comment: @Mehdi Yes, but it's the *rated* maximum. The phone might not ever *actually* draw that much: like how you might have a 5A kettle connected to a 13A mains plug.